# How to get Exception executing select statement ZF2

Tags: php, exception, pdo, zend-framework2

I'm getting a problem using ZF2 and DbAdapter.

I'm making a select statement and trying to get te exception when happen some error.

I have my select statement inside a block try... catch... but the problem is when I set a "wrong query", the exception is not threw.

Here my service:

```
return array(
    'db' => [
        'driver' => 'Pdo',
        'dsn' => 'mysql:dbname=my_dbname;host=localhost',
        'username' => 'root',
        'password' => 'root',
        'driver_options' => [
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES \'UTF8\'',
            PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
        ]
    ],
    'service_manager' => array(
        'factories' => array(
            'Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter' => function ($serviceManager) {
                $adapterFactory = new Zend\Db\Adapter\AdapterServiceFactory();
                $adapter = $adapterFactory->createService($serviceManager);

                \Zend\Db\TableGateway\Feature\GlobalAdapterFeature::setStaticAdapter($adapter);

                return $adapter;
            }
        ),
    ),
```

);

Here my query:

```
try {
            $db = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM `table`";
            $statement = $db->query($sql);
            $res = $statement->execute();
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Reivaldo, welcome to stackoverflow!

Since Zend DB drivers utilizing custom statement instances, Exceptions thrown by PDO and other possible errors handled internally and converting to `Zend\Db\Adapter\Exception` instances if necessary.

Check out [this  example](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-db/blob/master/src/Adapter/Driver/Mysqli/Statement.php#L206-L213).

Instead of catching the `PDOException` in your code, always catch possible exceptions from most specific one to most generic one. This is a good practice.

For example:

```
try {
    // code to throw exceptions
} catch (\Zend\Db\Adapter\Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    // This is not an adapter exception, anyway its an exception.
    echo $e->getMessage();
} finally {
    // This block always executed, an exception thrown or not.
}
```

You may also want to read some documentation about [exception handling](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php).